# Unable to submit to iTunes due to missing Home screen icon

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, apple-watch

Im not able to upload a watchkit 2 release to iTunes Connect. I get an error that the home screen icon for 42mm is missing. There is also no slot for this in Xcode (I use 7.1).

The error being returned is

> Error ITMS-90394: "Missing Icon. The watch application "...' is missing icon with pattern "*44x44@2x.png' (Home screen 42mm).

I've tried to edit the Contents.json file and add a second slot for "appLauncher" but that hasn't helped.

```
{  
  "size" : "44x44",  
  "idiom" : "watch",  
  "filename" : "AppIconWatch44x44@2x.png",  
  "scale" : "2x",  
  "role" : "appLauncher",  
  "subtype" : "42mm"  
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't understand your problem correctly - if you problem is that you don't have slots for 42mm in your image assets folder. Try adding new icon assets, like shown on the screenshot inside your image assets folder:

[image]

Check this settings too in attribute inspector:

[image]

P.S. You should keep in my mind, that your images should be `png` without alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks, you point me in the right direction. The problem was that in the Asset catalog settings i have not  enabled "watchOS 1.0". This results in the lack of the "Apple Watch Long Look" slot. After check and add the icon there i was able to upload. But it seems inconsistent for me. Target buiild is for watchOS 2.0, so this should not be needed, right. But anyway, now it works.

Comment: @roger Mark the question and answer as solved - it will be easier for other people, who have similiar problem

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that Tonic. Sure i've not forgot to do so and thanks again for pointing me to the right way.